# Declaration of functions in JavaScript as constants

Tags: javascript

Why do we use "const" declarator in declaration of functions in Javascript?

```
     const functionName= () => {
           ...
        }
```

Comment: [MDN - Function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

Comment: [It's an arrow function _expression_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which are different from [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Comment: So why do we use const declarator for arrow functions, I understand why do  we use const x = 5, but I do not understand why do I use const functionX

Answer (score 0):

```
const functionName = () => {
       return 15;
    }
```

Here an anonymous(lambda) function's result is assigning to a constant variable 'functionName'.
Just like const x = 5;

Lambda functions are used when you need a function for a short period of time. It has no function name. This is commonly used when you want to pass a function as an argument to higher-order functions, that is, functions that take other functions as their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function declaration
function add(){
}
// A variable declared
const add=()=>{
}
```

Function promotion occurs in function declarations,Variable declarations are not promoted

Comment: They are both functions but the difference is that the second one is an arrow function

Comment: The second one is actually called a functional expression